# How fast would an object at cruising altitude (around 10,600 m) need to travel to stay on the opposite side of the Earth to the Moon?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, orbital-motion, velocity, earth, moon

I am trying to figure out how fast an object will have to travel (at a height around 10,600 m) to never be in the presence of the moon. Meaning the object will always be on the opposite side of the moon to the Earth.

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/29190/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question partly because it was crossposted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It would have to orbit with the same angular velocity as the moon does around earth (about 0.5 degrees per hour or 360 degrees in a month).

0.5 degrees per hour translates to a velocity at radius $R=6,400 km$ (earth radius + cruising altitude, i.e. about the earth radius)

$$ \frac{2\pi}{720}\cdot R = 56 km/h$$

---

Of course this is just a rough estimate.

Comment: I think you forgot the earth's rotation. It would have to go about 1000mi/hour.

Comment: @zeta-band: Well, of course this was with respect to the non-rotating earth. As the earth rotates much faster than that, it could be basically ignored.